# How to get a 0-based week number in PHP similar to what MySQL offers?

Tags: php

In PHP week numbers are based on ISO-8601 which means that January 1st can be in the last week of the previous year:

```php
date('W', strtotime('2021-01-01')) === '53';
date('W', strtotime('2019-01-01')) === '01';
date('W', strtotime('2017-01-01')) === '52';
```

That's great because it's an international standard, but when ordering data that can result in unexpected results. MySQL on the other hand has [modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) that allow marking such a day as belonging to the zeroth week:

```sql
week('2021-01-01', 1) = 0,
week('2019-01-01', 1) = 1,
week('2017-01-01', 1) = 0,
```

Can that be replicated in PHP? I could probably make a check like this:

```php
$date = strtotime('2021-01-01');
$week = date('W', $date);

if (in_array($week, [52, 53]) && date('m', $date) === '01') {
    $week = 0;
}
```

but I'm wondering if that's exactly equivalent, there are often edge cases when working with dates.

Comment: `if (in_array($week, [52, 53]) && date('m', $date) === '01') {$week = 0;}` Not sure if that always applies.

Comment: @B001ᛦ any clue on when it wouldn't work? Only weeks can span two years so the second part of the condition must be correct. 54th week is impossible and 51st is too far for Jan 1st to be a part of so the first part should be good too. But yeah, I'd like there to be a built-in way to get that :)

Comment: _..any clue on when it wouldn't work?..._ Not really but it might be helpful to take a look at https://www.calendar-week.org/calendar-weeks/2021.. You can choose any other year just for a quick view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to verify my own suggestion. I took the first 10 days of the year over a few hundred years and compared the results given by my algorithm and MySQL. There were no differences, so unless it can be done with built-in code or a library like Carbon, I'm sticking with it.

Here's the test code for reference. It uses \DB::select() method from the Laravel framework to query the database.

```php
$getWeek = function($date) {
    $stamp = strtotime($date);
    $week = (int) date('W', $stamp);

    if (in_array($week, [52, 53]) && date('m', $stamp) === '01') {
        $week = 0;
    }

    return $week;
};

$errorCount = 0;

for ($year = 1801; $year <= 2200; $year++) {
    foreach (range(1, 10) as $day) {
        $fullDate = "$year-01-$day";
        echo $fullDate . ' ';
        $phpWeek = $getWeek($fullDate);
        echo $phpWeek . ' ';
        $dbWeek = \DB::select("select week('$fullDate', 1) as week")[0]->week;
        echo $dbWeek . ' ';
        if ($phpWeek !== $dbWeek) {
            echo 'error! ';
            $errorCount++;
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
die("$errorCount errors\n");
```